# How to be sure that async script is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have task to load some stats script asynchronously and then use it's api.

```
const getCounter = async id => {
    let counter = window[`counter${id}`];
    if (!counter) {
        let script = document.querySelectorAll(`[src="${STATS_URL}"]`);
        if (!script.length) {
            script = document.createElement('script');
            await new Promise(resolve => {
                script.onload = resolve;

                script.src = STATS_URL;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            });
        }
        counter = window[`counter${id}`] = new window.Stats.createCounter({ id });
    }
    return counter;
};
```

But, every time I'm trying to get `counter` for the first time (or few first times) I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createCounter' of undefined`

Looks like `await` not truly awaits for `Promise` to resolve and attempting to create counter.

My second guess is that `await` is working, but before script assigns `Stats` to `window`.

How I can be sure, that the `stats script` is **fully loaded** and did *all* **it's internal work**?

Comment: getCounter.then(() => { console.log("do your work here");} )

Comment: I'm using `counter = await getCounter(COUNTER_ID)`

Comment: You have to move `..new window.Stats.createCounter..` statement into Promise callback

Comment: Afaik, the script being loaded (`onload`) doesn't necessarily imply that is has been executed. Rather use the execution of the script itself to resolve the promise, AMD-style.

Comment: Definetly, but it's not the point

Comment: @hindmost Using `await` basically *is* a promise callback

Comment: @Bergi, how can i use script execution if i don't know it's internals? By now I see only case when i constantly (with timeouts) check if script has been executed and i can use it's api

Comment: @ezhikov I meant that the script should make use of the [AMD api](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md)